# Splitting data frame from defined columns onward yet maintaining first two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Probe' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e'],
                 'Gene' : ['one', 'two','three','four','five'],
                 'X' : randn(5), 'Y' : randn(5)})
```

That looks like this:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
    Gene Probe         X         Y
0    one     a  0.104504  1.089442
1    two     b  0.030071  0.696786
2  three     c  1.224704  1.077867
3   four     d -0.052333  0.034292
4   five     e -0.283872  0.602743
```

What I want to do is to split this data frame for column `X` onward and keeping 
the first and second column yielding:

```
    Gene Probe         X
0    one     a  0.104504
1    two     b  0.030071
2  three     c  1.224704
3   four     d -0.052333
4   five     e -0.283872
```

and

```
    Gene Probe         Y
0    one     a  1.089442
1    two     b  0.696786
2  three     c  1.077867
3   four     d  0.034292
4   five     e  0.602743
```

I tried this but it did give what I expected:

```
for dfs in df.groupby(['Probe','Gene']):
    print dfs
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: so you want two dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a start:

```
df_x = df.loc[:, ['Gene', 'Probe', 'X']]
df_y = df.loc[:, ['Gene', 'Probe', 'Y']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `difference` to remove the column you're not interested in to subselect your columns:

```
In [9]:

X = df[df.columns.difference(['Y'])]
Y = df[df.columns.difference(['X'])]
print(X)
Y
    Gene Probe         X
0    one     a  1.231749
1    two     b  0.519425
2  three     c  0.849960
3   four     d -0.077796
4   five     e  1.224163
Out[9]:
    Gene Probe         Y
0    one     a  0.022695
1    two     b  0.500311
2  three     c -0.163624
3   four     d  0.411491
4   five     e  1.305214
```